# Why doesn't G Suite Admin password reset option appear?

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business, account-recovery

I am providing support to a small organisation that had G Suite set up for them a few years ago by a company that has now folded.

They have given me the account name for the G Suite domain admin, but none of the passwords they have provided is correct.

According to the documentation, the next step to recover the account seems to be to have a password reset link sent to whichever of their staff's email addresses or phone numbers was set up as the fall back. (If that fails, the next step will be to recover the domain by changing their DNS entries.)

However, I cannot work out how to trigger the password reset link. It doesn't appear for this account, when it does for other domain admin accounts.

1. I visit http://accounts.google.com
2. I enter the domain admin email address, and select Next.

   - I know the email address is right, because if I put in another one at the same domain, I get an error about it not being recognized.
3. Faced with a password box, I select "Forgot password?"
4. It prompts for "the last password you remember". I try one of the various options that have been provided to me. (Or I select "Try a different question", and get the same result.)
5. With other domain admin accounts, at this point I get presented with an option to send a reset to a back up email or phone number, but for this account I get presented with a page saying "Couldn't sign you in" and "Contact your domain admin for help".

How can I trigger the domain admin password reset link to be sent out to associated address? What is different about this account which is preventing the option from appearing.

(Failing that, how can I initiate the domain recovery process, where they challenge me to change the settings on the name-server to prove I control the domain?)

[Updated to show that I am following the right process, but that it doesn't work for this email address.]

Comment: This kind of help request should be asked directly through the [official G Suite help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/apps)

Answer (score 0):

Below link may help you out...

[Reset your administrator password](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561?hl=en)

You can try the domain verification method. Be sure your domain based g-suite mail id is super administrator id.

Comment: Thanks, but that describes how to do steps 1-3 as I do them above, and then says "follow the instructions that appear". It is precisely because these instructions aren't helpful that I am asking here.

Comment: A raw link generally isn't helpful. Granted, this is a link to Google's official support page, but you're making the reader go to yet _another_ site to get an answer. Better to give a synopsis of the solution here and leave the link as credit to the source and a place to go if more information is needed.

Comment: If you didn't know the previous password and recovery e-mail address, You can try the CNAME verification method ( Server access needed ).  I don't think so that link is not much helpful.

Comment: If I cannot get the password to be sent to the recovery e-mail address (and I can't see how!), I will resort to the CNAME verification method... but HOW? I cannot get G Suite to offer me these options.

Comment: Sorry, @Oddthinking.  I thought your logging in e-mail address is a super admin id of that particular domain. From your 5th point, I realize that id is not a super admin id. Recovery e-mail address and CNAME option only come when the login id is a super administrator. [ CNAME verification method helps when the phone and email options are not helpful. CNAME is a type of DNS record. ]

Comment: It *is* the domain admin id. See the updated version to show that this account does not act as it should.

Comment: If that is your domain admin ID, You will get the multiple recovery options surely. I have checked the updated G-Suite  just now only.

Comment: No, I am not getting the multiple recovery options, and yet it appears to be my domain id. That is why I am asking the question - is there something I may have missed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting this sentence - and yet it appears to be my domain ID. Are you getting multiple recovery options for any other domain based G-suite id ?

Comment: You can resolve this issue by collecting all Id's from your client and check one by one for which one is admin ID. I think you are not the created the G-suite fist time for that client. You can check with that old IT vendor of that client who created the G-Suite.