# How to identify the Super Admin email of your GoogleApps

Tags: google-account, google-workspace-for-business, account-recovery, g-suite-administrator

Our network guy left sometime ago, covid n all. He never told us which/what email was the super admin in our org. been over 5 months now.

1. We are trying to add new users, how c**an we add new users** to our org.
2. Any suggestions on **how to find out which email is the super admin**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the administrator email address you have to do the regular account recovery procedure for Google accounts but you might have an additional option that is to demonstrate the domain ownership. For details see [Reset your administrator password](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561?hl=en)

Related

- [How do I recover my Google account (or Gmail) password or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52706/88163)
- [Why doesn't G Suite Admin password reset option appear?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103718/88163)
- [Google Apps account for domain suspending](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/111608/88163)